# Make dialog width the same as custom positive button width

Tags: android

I am using a custom layout for a dialog like this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Builder builder = new Builder(getActivity());
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_code_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    builder.setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            listener.onDialogPositiveClick(CodeDialogFragment.this);
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

With this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="XXX.fragments.CodeDialogFragment">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/code_text"
    android:padding="@dimen/medium_body_padding"
    android:id="@+id/code_text"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am replacing the standard positive button with my styled one by overriding the onStart() method on the dialog fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //replace default button with image

    Button button = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.getActivity(), R.drawable.copy_and_open_btn));
}
```

My problem is that my deisgn requires the dialog to be the same width as the button, but as the button is being overridden setting the width to `wrap_content` isn't working. How can I change the width of the dialog to match the button width after the button has been replaced?

Update:

I have managed to change the width of the dialog by adding this to the `onStart()` method:

```
    int width = button.getBackground().getIntrinsicWidth();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = width;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

This changes the width of the dialog, but shrinks the button to retain the padding. I can't work out where that padding is coming from though.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but what happens if you do `setView` after `setPositiveButton`?

Comment: No, that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you don't skin your positive button, but make the whole Dialog custom?

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_code_dialog);

Button doneButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onDialogPositiveClick(CodeDialogFragment.this);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

In this case your positive button (R.id.done_button) is a Button inside your layout (R.layout.fragment_code_dialog). You can layout your view and button exactly as in your design and use that as a whole, instead of having to skin the Positive Button.

Answer (score 1):

Just set

```
getWindow().setLayout(int width,int height)` immediately after `show()
```

for example.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//do other operations like inflating layout,setTile etc here
builder.show().getWindow().setLayout(600,900);'
```